# get_the_category() doesn't work inside <figcaption>

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am facing an odd issue. I am trying to use one of the [js script](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/) gallery on my wordpress theme. I want to display category of post as a figcaption, but when I put my PHP code inside it doesn't work. When I paste the same code outside  tags it works like a charm.

Note that script is doing something because if there are more than 2 cateogories it is pritning commas , however doesn't show category name.

```
 <div class="grid">
          <figure class="effect-sarah">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <figcaption>
              <h2>**Category: <span>  <?php $categories=get_the_category(); $separator=", " ; $output='' ; if ($categories) { foreach ($categories as $category) { $output .='<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator; } echo trim($output, $separator); } ?></span>**</h2>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View more</a>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>


        <div class="title-excerpt">
          <h3> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <small> <?php the_time( 'F j, Y g:i a'); ?></small></h3>
        </div>
      Category: <span>  <?php $categories=get_the_category(); $separator=", " ; $output='' ; if ($categories) { foreach ($categories as $category) { $output .='<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator; } echo trim($output, $separator); } ?></span>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View more</a>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming both calls to `get_the_category()` are within the loop? (e.g. the one in `<figcaption>` is not somewhere completely different) ... it's hard to tell if your code is grouped together for the sake of demonstration, or if it's truly coded exactly like that.

Comment: And of course, the reason I ask, is that `get_the_category()` needs a `$post_id` if it's used outside the loop.

Comment: Also, if you were to bring up a developer toolbar (e.g. firebug, or chrome dev tools) and look at those two commas, what do you see? Is it: `<h2>Category: <span>,,</span></h2>`?

Comment: I paste you  code exactly as it is in the code. both are within content.php so they indeed are inside loop.

Comment: I uploaded code here: http://www.wp.brandflow.pl/

My index.php code:
     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format()); endwhile; else : echo '<p>No content found</p>'; endif; ?>

And content.php is in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your PHP is working wonderfully. You can confirm that by inspecting the page and seeing this html:

[image: a snapshot of html showing all links]

The problem is the CSS. Specifically, there is a lot of CSS around the `figure` and `figcaption` elements, and their descendant `a` tags. The very **first** clue (and I believe there's several problems) is this little bit of CSS:

[image]

This makes the link indent 200% (e.g. double the tabs), sets its font-size to 0 (e.g. so small it can't be seen), as well as its opacity to 0 (e.g. even if it was bigger, it'd be completely transparent).

I know this doesn't "answer" your question per se, but it does clarify that your PHP is not the problem!